# Colocar marcadores do tipo disc ou circle ou square não funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Fiz isso

```
<tr class="espaco-branco table-prod-add">
   <ul type="disc">
       <li>
           <td style="white-space: nowrap;">                           
             @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage
           </td>
        </li>
   </ul>
</tr>
```

Acontece que o texto que está em `@mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage` não vem com aquela "bolinha" ou "quadradinho" na frente. O que está acontecendo?

Está assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe pela imagem, que mesmo sem texto o square ou disc fica aparecendo e antes da linha vertical e meu código agora, para essa imagem está assim, tentando não imprimir o square num texto vazio

```
<tr class="espaco-branco table-prod-add">
   <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <ul>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage))
        {
           <li style="list-style: square; margin-left: 15px">             
                @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage
           </li>
         }
      </ul>
    </td>                                        
</tr>
```

Só não entendo porque que o saquare está fora da table, conforme imagem, aplicando o código acima. Com o código acima eliminei o square quando o mainItem for null ou vazio, agora só preciso entender o porque que o square ou disc está fora da table

Comment: porque não se pode colocar uma lista dentro de uma linha (tr), coloque dentro da td que vai funcionar

Comment: @RicardoPontual, então fiz conforme o sua sugestão e não funcionou também. O que acho estranho que a <ul> não reconhece o type. Ele aceita typeof, mas não type. `<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                            <ul type="square">
                                                <li>
                                                    @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td>   `

Comment: Fazendo assim: `<td style="list-style: square">` eu consigo, porém há uma linha vertical(limitando a tr) e o texto fica dentro dessa linha, mas o square fica fora.

Comment: Resolvi o problema do vazio. A questão toda é que o disc fica fora da linha, conforme imagem e o texto dentro. Para colocar o disc dentro, eu tenho que setar a Margin, mas não gostaria disso. O que tenho que fazer?

Comment: tranquilo, mas novamente, a tr não foi feita pra fazer layout com uma lista, aninhado logo abaixo da tr deve ser um td ou th, se precisa de uma linha para um layout deveria usar um elemento como div com o display como inline ou inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Veja o código que colocou no comentário:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
       <ul type="square">
         <li> @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
       <ul type="disc">
         <li> @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Aparece perfeitamente, usando a lista no lugar certo (dentro da td) aparece certo

Comment: Não consegui colocando na tag `<UL>`. Só funciona na <li> e com `style="list-style: square"`. Com apenas type="square" ou "disc", não funciona

Comment: Com esse código: `<tr class="espaco-branco table-prod-add">                                       <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
      <ul>
           @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage))
           {
               <li style="list-style: square">
                   @mainItem.ShoppingCartMessage
               </li>
            }
      </ul>
    </td>                                        
  </tr>` e o square continua fora dos limites da table

Comment: Se eu coloco a margin-left da lista para 15 ou mais px, aí o disc ou square fica ok, mas não gostaria de fixar manualmente com valor em pixels, devido a diversos browsers usados pelos clientes, poderia dar "tilt". Alguém tem alguma sugestão?